# Why my web site can't be reached using my domain address?

Tags: dns, nginx, domain, dig

I have created a DNS server using following files, to map my domain address `sudia.com` into my VPS server, but it doesn't work and I can't reach to my server using my domain address.  also must say there is an NginX running on `http://136.243.197.164:3200`.

/etc/named.conf:

```
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        allow-query     { localhost; 136.243.197.164;};

        /*
         - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
         - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable
           recursion.
         - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access
           control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
           cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification
           attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
           reduce such attack surface
        */
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";

        /* https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CryptoPolicy */
        include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

//forward zone
zone "sudia.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "fwd.sudia.com.db";
        allow-update { none; };
        allow-query  { any; };
};

//backward zone
zone "197.243.136.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "sudia.com.rev";
        allow-update { none; };
        allow-query  { any; };
};
```

/var/named/fwd.sudia.com.db:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     ns1.sudia.com. ns2.sudia.com. (
                                              3           ;Serial
                                              3600        ;Refresh
                                              1800        ;Retry
                                              604800      ;Expire
                                              86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

;Name Server Information
@       IN  NS      ns1.sudia.com.

;IP address of Name Server
ns1       IN  A       136.243.197.164

;A - Record HostName To Ip Address
www     IN  A       136.243.197.164

;CNAME record
ftp     IN CNAME        www.sudsuz.com.
```

/var/named/sudia.com.rev:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     ns1.sudia.com. ns2.sudia.com. (
                                       3           ;Serial
                                       3600        ;Refresh
                                       1800        ;Retry
                                       604800      ;Expire
                                       86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

;Name Server Information
@         IN      NS         ns1.sudia.com.

;Reverse lookup for Name Server
164        IN  PTR     ns1.sudia.com.

;PTR Record IP address to HostName
164      IN  PTR     www.sudia.com
```

EDIT: This is the result of `host www.sudia.com`:

```
www.sudia.com has address 136.243.197.164
```

But `host sudia.com` (without `www`) doesn't work!

Comment: looks like external access is working, is this accessing via domain name on the same network?

Comment: @SQLTemp, May you explain more?

Comment: You don’t define an A record for `sudsaz.com`…?

Comment: @DanielB: What do you mean by A record? Should I create a new file than what I put above?

Comment: In your forward zone (`fwd.sudsaz.com.db`), you do not have an A record defined for `sudsaz.com`. Only for `www.sudsaz.com`.

Comment: @DanielB: May you post your suggestion as an answer? I don't know how exactly I must add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by @DanielB, excluding other possible issues, you appear to be missing an A record for the naked domain. An example of this type of A record would be:

```
sudia.com.     IN  A       136.243.197.164
```

So, an updated version of your example zone might be:

*ex. var/named/fwd.sudia.com.db*

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     ns1.sudia.com. root.sudia.com. (
                                            4           ;Serial
                                            3600        ;Refresh
                                            1800        ;Retry
                                            604800      ;Expire
                                            86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

;Name Server Information
@       IN  NS      ns1.sudia.com.

;IP address of Name Server
ns1       IN  A       136.243.197.164

;A - Record HostName To IP Address
sudia.com.     IN  A       136.243.197.164
www            IN  A       136.243.197.164

;CNAME record
ftp     IN CNAME        www.sudsuz.com.
```

Comment: Presumably, `$ORIGIN` already is `sudsaz.com.`, so simply using `@` should do, too.

Comment: @Anaksunaman: `http://www.sudsaz.com:3200/` doesn't work for me!

Comment: I chenged the file like the what answer suggests but when I check `www.sudsaz.com` in `https://www.whatismyip.com/dns-lookup/` it has no results. Previously it had the same problem with `sudsaz.com` but it solved, but new problem with `www.sudsaz.com` happens.

Comment: @user3486308 `http://136.243.197.164:3200` no longer works for me, either, which shouldn't be DNS related. Did you make additional changes to the server?